# Prevent $routeParams from Bleeding Through Codebase

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am using the Angular $routeProvider service to wire-up my single-page HTML5 applciation. I am using the following routing configuration:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/show-order/:orderId', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/order.html',
        controller: 'ShowOrdersController'
      });
  }]);
```

Within the `ShowOrdersController` I need access to the RESTful URL parameter described above as `:orderId`. It is suggested that to best achieve this, I should use the `$routeParams` service in my controller:

```
app.controller('ShowOrderController', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.order_id = $routeParams.orderId; 
});
```

I have *serious* concerns about this. My routing logic has now bled through to my controller! If I want to drastically change the routing scheme, I would have to go through all my controller code and correct all the references to `$routeParams`.

Furthermore, if I want to re-use the `ShowOrderController` for multiple routes, it's going to enforce all of the routes to use the same token variable `:orderId`.

This just seems like poor coding to me. It would make more sense to provide some *linking* mechanism, so the router can specify well-known parameters to the controller.

This would be just like how a modal's `resolve` method works:

```
$modal.open({
  controller: 'ShowOrderController',
  resolve: {
    orderId: function () {
      return $routeParams.orderId;
    }
  }
});

app.controller("ShowOrderController", ["orderId", function (orderId, $scope) {
  $scope.orderId = orderId;
}]);
```

Is there any way to achieve this or something similar with the out-of-the-box AngularJS routing services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [AngularJS - How to pass up to date $routeParams to resolve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878850/angularjs-how-to-pass-up-to-date-routeparams-to-resolve) it is possible to reference the current route's parameters in the `resolve` method of the `$routeProvider` using `$route.current.params`:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/show-order/:orderId', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/order.html',
        controller: 'ShowOrdersController',
        resolve: {
          orderId: function( $route ) {
            return $route.current.params.orderId;
          }
        }
      });
  }]);
```

This will then honour the suggestion above, that the controller can declaratively specify its parameters:

```
app.controller("ShowOrderController", ["orderId", function (orderId, $scope) {
   $scope.orderId = orderId;
}]);
```

In conjunction, this effectively decouples the controller from the route's parameters.