# can't access the returned correctly returned $routeParams using a dot (.)

Tags: angularjs, routes

I think my problem is accesssing it the code works fine until that line tried the log for $routeParams and returned well as shown but cant access it with a dot for specific attributes

```
                var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid', 'ngRoute', "ngAnimate", "ngAria", 'ngMaterial']);
            var statusLabel;
            var selectedItem;

            myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider)
            {
                $routeProvider.
                when('/:energyId/:energyChain/:resourceId/:facilityId',
                {
                    templateUrl: '/Content/resourceTemplate.html',
                    controller: 'detailsController'

                }).
                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/param1/param1/param1/param1'
                });
            }]);

            myApp.controller('detailsController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
                //After testing the following code returns   {"energyId":"param1","energyChain":"param1","resourceId":"param1","facilityId":"param1"}  for matching url
                //but when i try to access it like $routeParams.energyId it say Undefined the problems seems accessing the returned value 
                $scope.statusLabel = $routeParams;
                //this is the error
                $scope.label = $routeParams.energyId;
```

**The error is accessing the details in the routeparams **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) for $routeProvider

> Be aware that ngRoute.$routeParams will still refer to the previous
>   route within these resolve functions. Use $route.current.params to
>   access the new route parameters, instead.

So..

```
$scope.label =  $route.current.params.energyId;
```

[Referred from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878850/angularjs-how-to-pass-up-to-date-routeparams-to-resolve)

Comment: tnks let me try and will be back